# Adding a custom field to a custom taxonomy in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, tags, taxonomy, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I have 2 Custom Taxonomies in my WooCommerce shop; I can see them when I click on "Products -> Attributes". One of them is called "Bearbeiter", so I click on the right side of "Bearbeiter" on "Edit Tags". Now I see the 3 entries/"Bearbeiters" :-).

For each of them I can edit 3 fields/tags: 
Name, Slug, Description

I would like to add a fourth field under "Description", called "Address". Have searched and tried various sources and scripts, but I don't seem to be able to get the right hook or the right function.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research on the web I found many old posts with code that was not / no longer working.

But this one here works: https://sabramedia.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-custom-taxonomies

So I declare this problem solved!